# Прочитать два числа с клавиатуры

Tags: java

Как реализовать на Java такое чтение: *scanf("%d%*c%d", &x, &y);* ?
Плюс нужен контроль ввода: чтобы программа не вылетала, если ввести строку

Comment: не это? http://javarevisited.blogspot.ru/2012/08/how-to-format-string-in-java-printf.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эт вам не Ся... :)

Самый простой, незамороченный способ использовать [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) - фактически это такой небольшой парсерочек, который входной поток разбивает на токены и далее уже можно с токенами делать что надо - типа:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    int myInt = sc.nextInt();
}
```